# Can I assign delegate sub to AddHandler using AddressOf?

Tags: vb.net, delegates, printdocument

Edit: my orginal question was too confusing.

```
Public Class PrintResults

    Public Sub ResultsToPS(ByVal lis As List(Of FileData), ByVal PSPathName As String) 
        Me.List = lis

        'setup report writer
        Dim rep As New Helper.Report

        'create report to PS
        rep.ToPS(PSPathName)

    End Sub


Public Class Report
    Public Sub New()
        PrintDoc = New Printing.PrintDocument
    End Sub

    Public WithEvents PrintDoc As Printing.PrintDocument

    Public PrintDocPrintPage As PrintDoc_PrintPage
    Public Delegate Sub PrintDoc_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
                        ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) 'Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage 

    Public Function ToPS(ByVal PSPathName As String) As String

        'fails
        AddHandler Me.PrintDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintDocPrintPage

        Me.PrintDoc.Print()

    End Function
```

AddHandler has compiler error: AddressOf operand must be the name of a method.  Is there any way to assign the handler to a delegate sub?

Comment: Your current class inter-dependencies are quite confusing.  Presumably, you want `Report` to be the main class, but you want to be able to assign an instance of `PrintResults` to `Report` that allow customized printing of the `List(Of FileData)` to `PSPathName` by calling a method in `Report`.  Does that described your goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some research I found it's not possible to use a delegate sub with AddressOf. So we need a different approach. I see it now that all I have to do is instantiate the PrintDoc in the New sub. Now I have a PrintDoc object for the AddHandler to use.

```
Public Class Report
    Public Sub New()
        PrintDoc = New Printing.PrintDocument
    End Sub
```

We use the regular AddHandler with no delegates:

```
Public Class PrintResults

    Public Sub ResultsToPS(ByVal lis As List(Of FileData), ByVal PSPathName As String) 
        Me.List = lis

        'setup report writer
        Dim rep As New Helper.Report

        'PrintDoc is automatically instatiated so no object error
        AddHandler rep.PrintDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintDoc_PrintPage      

        'create report to PS
        rep.ToPS(PSPathName)

    End Sub
```

[Delegates and the AddressOf Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74wy9422(v=vs.90).aspx)

[AddHandler Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating events and attaching a function to it is what you are looking for.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim c As New TestClass

    AddHandler c.OnComplete, AddressOf Test

    c.Execute() ' Will print Done

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Sub Test()
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
End Sub

Class TestClass

    Public Event OnComplete()

    Public Sub Execute()
        RaiseEvent OnComplete()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm already doing. I call `rep.InitiatePrintDoc()` to instantiate `PrintDoc`. Then I add the handler to the newly created `PrintDoc`. Then I print. Fine! But I don't want to instantiate first. I thought I could assign a delegate, then have the "Report" class instantiate the object then add the handler itself. But it's not working.